# onPrepared causing one user an error

Tags: android, media-player

I've had this simple program out for about two months and the other night an error showed up for a user and I don't understand why.

```
public class mainmenu extends Activity implements OnPreparedListener {
    private PopupWindow pw;
    public static int RandomNum;
    public static String quickStart;
    private dbadapter mydbhelper;
    MediaPlayer mpButtonClick;
    Intent intent;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mainmenu);




    Button bsound = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bCategories);
    bsound.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick(View v) {
            quickStart = "Cate";
            onPrepared(mpButtonClick);
            intent = new Intent ("wanted.pro.madlibslite.CATEGORIES");
            intent.putExtra("quickStart", quickStart);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });



    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            moveTaskToBack(true);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    //Menu Items
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.mainmenu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
             case R.id.help:
               showHelp();
                return true;
           }
        return false;
    }

        private void showHelp() {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
                       this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                     pw = new PopupWindow(
                       inflater.inflate(R.layout.help, null, false), 
                       LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
                       true);
                     pw.showAtLocation(this.findViewById(R.id.bCategories), Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0); 
        }
        public void onClickHelp(View helper){pw.dismiss();

        }   
        //QuickStart
        public void onClickQuick(View main) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Quick Start only available in full version.", 1000).show();
            //RandomNum = (int) (Math.random()*101);
            //quickStart = "Quick";
            //mpButtonClick.start();
            //startActivity(new Intent("wanted.pro.madlibslite.INPUTPAGE"));


        }

        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player) {
            mpButtonClick.setOnPreparedListener(this);
            try {
                mpButtonClick.prepare();

            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mpButtonClick.start();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            mydbhelper = dbadapter.getInstance(mainmenu.this);
            mydbhelper.open();
            mpButtonClick = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.button50);
            super.onResume();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            mpButtonClick.release();
            super.onPause();
        }

}
```

The error in question...

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at wanted.pro.madlibslite.mainmenu.onPrepared(mainmenu.java:107)
at wanted.pro.madlibslite.mainmenu$1.onClick(mainmenu.java:45)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9089)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3806)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Sadly I don't have what device they are on. But hoping someone here might see something I'm doing wrong that would cause the onprepared to error.

Answer (score 0):

The only variable that can cause a NullPointerException in the onPrepared method is: `mpButtonClick`. So let's try to figure out how `mpButtonClick` can ever be null...

In the onResume method you are creating a new MediaPlayer, and assigning it to the variable mpButtonClick. However, what you may have missed is that sometimes MediaPlayers can fail to be created. As the Android Documentation says for the static method [`MediaPlayer.create(Context context, int resid)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#create%28android.content.Context,%20int%29):

> **Returns**
>
> a MediaPlayer object, or null if creation failed

That's right -- that method will not always necessarily return a valid MediaPlayer. It will return null whenever it was unable to create a MediaPlayer. Which then causes your onPrepared method to access a null variable - hence the NullPointerException.